# How to make div tag clickable link?

Tags: html

How to make div a link? I cant figure it out. 
my code looks like that

```
   <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4 kolLD"></div>
```

Comment: Do you need there a `div`? Why not `<a class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4 kolLD"></a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML 5 states that the `<a>` element

> may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth,
>   even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content
>   within (e.g. buttons or other links)

You just can wrap your div tag with an `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="#"><div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4 kolLD"></div></a>
```

Comment: A citation would make this answer even better.

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what i was looking for